# What is the best way to share data between different JUnit test classes

Tags: java, json, design-patterns, junit

I am writing JUnit tests for a big application and the objects are too big to initialize inside the code itself. So we  decided to put the object inside JSON files.

Now it's more readable and the code is clean. But as I was wiring my code I understand that the same JSON file could be shareed among other test classes.
I don't want to parse it again and again in each test.

I thought about a singleton, but maybe there is a nicer way to do it via rules or by inheritance?

Comment: What do you mean by "the objects are too big to initialize inside the code"? Do you mean it takes too long or consumes too much memory?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely prefer composition over inheritance. I.e. "has-a" and not "is-a". So, if re-parsing the file is not viable, singleton doesn't sound to frightening. Make sure the singleton is immutable. If you need to share fields between two different test cases declared in the same test class, then you may use a static.

Always be vary of sharing state between different test cases as they should be executed in their own isolated environment and not be dependent on other test cases.

Comment: The same mechanism of loading the json file is for all the test class
So I thought to do inheritance that will have foundation for others that want to load there json files.
basically what  I am doing I am loading the file to cache. in the BeforeClass and then loading the object before each test.

Comment: Every test can change the object this is way I am reloading befor each test.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a system property to the jvm which is a key value mapping between two strings. The string key can point to a string value which is the absolute directory path of the json file you want to share across test classes. How to share data more complex than a string, I'm not sure how or if it's possible.